# range-based for loop in a function

Tags: arrays, function, c++11, for-loop

I programmed in C for a while and now I'm new to C++. I have to replace the for-loops in a C-Programm with the range-based for loops of C++11.
This is the actual code:

```
 void sort1(int num[], int start, int end) {
  int finished = 0, i;

  while(!finished) {
    finished = 1;
    for(i=start ; i<end ; i++) {
      if(num[i] > num[i+1]) {
        swap(num, i, i+1);
        finished = 0;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And this is what I changed it to:

```
void sort1(int num[], int start, int end) {
  bool finished = 0;

  while(!finished) {
    finished = 1;
    for(int i : num) {
      if(i > i+1) {
        swap(num, i, i+1);
        finished = 0;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I cannot even compile it, it gives me the error:
error: no matching function for call to 'begin(int*&)'

(Sorry if my english is a bit weird :D)

Comment: `num` decays to `int *`, so you cannot call `std::begin` on it.

Comment: @remyabel: `num` does not decay to a pointer, it is a pointer. (There might have been decay in the calling function, but that's a different thing.)

Comment: I would change the type of num[] to std::array instead of a plain array which decays to a pointer when handed over to a function like this. You can then pass the array by reference and your function should work as it should.